# If-statement string strange comparaison

Tags: php, if-statement

I've probably miss something but I realy don't understand that :

```
if(trim($_GET[$slug]) == trim($cat->$slug)) {
    $selected = 'selected';
}
else {
    $selected = '';
}

var_dump(trim($_GET[$slug]));
var_dump(trim($cat->slug));
var_dump($selected);
```

Show :

```
string(8) "albanais" 
string(8) "albanais" 
string(0) ""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be using `$cat->slug` inside the if statement rather than `$cat->$slug`

Comment: Could you state why that is? It helps to give an explanation.

Comment: Thank you a lot and sry for my question. I'm blind ^^. It's time to rest ;)